# MongoDB - Further transform an aggregated list

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm fairly new to Mongo aggregations, and my current Mongo-fu has reached its limit.

As an example, let's assume a collection of "hike" records with the following document structure:

```
{ 
  hiker_id: 123,
  trail: "Dusty Peak"
}
```

Were I to use

```
db.hikes.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$hiker_id", trails: {$addToSet: "$trail"}}}])
```

I'd get something like:

```
{
  _id: 123,
  trails: ["Dusty Peak", "Windy Falls", "Mushroom Alley", ...
}
```

However, if one hiker had hiked the same trail multiple times, we'd see repeats in the `trails` list, so what I'd really like is:

```
 {
  _id: 123,
  trails: { "Dusty Peak": 2, 
            "Windy Falls": 1, 
            "Mushroom Alley": 4,
            ...
          }
}
```

A summary of how many times the hiker has hiked each trail. How would I do that with `aggregate`?

**--or--**

Is this something should instead be done in the *finalize* step of a Map-Reduce? Mongo's own documentation says that MR has worse performance, and performance is critical for what I'm working on.

Comment: I would recommend separating your concerns here.  I would do the update with $addToSet  and then do the aggregation pipelines and count the references.

Comment: I completely agree, and that would be easy for me at the language level, but at the Mongo level I'm not sure of the semantics.

Comment: if you do your $addtoSet first, then you can do a aggregate and use $sum to count the fields.

Comment: @jmugz3 Note that `$addToSet` will of course only produce a "count" of 1 for each reference. That's the nature of this. There is a much easier way when you consider what `$addToSet` is actually doing.

Comment: if you really want to see your result in custom format, then you'll need to use mongodb map-reduce. However, you can use aggregation framework to have slight different looking document.

Comment: @BlakesSeven just saw your answer. I have used two $match before, but never two $group. I guess it is possible.Btw, that's a nice way of doing this.

Comment: It's a pipeline! So that means you can put whatever and however many stages in there as you like, as long as the following order makes sense. Though what @Saleem says is true and you could get the "named keys" from mapReduce, since it is using JavaScript interpretation it does run much slower. For mine the aggregation process with different output structure works better, and you can always "transform" the results after they are returned as is demonstrated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) operator is really just another kind of [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), but just contained to array entries as a result. So to count the occurances of those keys, simply "group" on them as well. A second `$group` can put them into an array:

```js
db.hikes.aggregate([
    // Group on distinct trail per hiker
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "hiker": "$hiker_id",
            "trail": "$trail"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},

    // Now roll-up per hiker and push to array
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.hiker",
        "trails": {
            "$push": { "name": "$_id.trail", "count": "$count" }
        }
    }}
])
```

This gives you are result like:

```js
 {
     "_id": 123,
     "trails": [
         { "name": "Dusty Peak", "count": 2 },
         { "name": "Windy Falls", "count": 1 },
         { "name": "Mushroom Alley", "count": 4 }
     ]
 }
```

If you think about it then really all the results you need are actually achieved in the first `$group` pipeline stage, albeit in one document per trail per hiker. All the second `$group` is doing ( and actually quite quickly ) is just "rolling-up" the results per hiker by adding the rest of the information into an array.

That's not the same as what you suggest, but it's what the aggregation framework does. It does not transform "data" to "keys" in any way. IMHO this is a good thing since I don't think that "named keys" that represent data points are a good idea. The above is clean and easily iterable as a natural array. And of course all the required data is there.

If you really have your heart set on tranforming to keys, then the above still applies and it's better to just do the tranformation client side:

```js
db.hikes.aggregate([
    // Group on distinct trail per hiker
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "hiker": "$hiker_id",
            "trail": "$trail"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},

    // Now roll-up per hiker and push to array
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.hiker",
        "trails": {
            "$push": { "name": "$_id.trail", "count": "$count" }
        }
    }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    var newTrails = {};
    doc.trails.forEach(function(trail) {
        newTrails[trail.name] = trail.count;
    });
    doc.trails = newTrails;
    printjson(doc);
})
```

Or basically that similar iterator pattern in whatever language implementation you use.

---

For the record, the mapReduce way of doing this would be:

```js
db.hikes.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var data = {};
        data[this.trail] = 1;
        emit(this.hiker_id,data);
    },
    function(key,values) {
        var result = {};
        values.forEach(function(value) {
            Object.keys(value).forEach(function(key) {
                if (!result.hasOwnProperty(key))
                    result[key] = 0;
                result[key] += value[key];
            })
        });
        return result;
    },
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Which to my mind is kind of silly since additional "grouping" relies on iterating object keys. The result also has it's own mapReduce quirks:

```js
 {
     "_id": 123,
     "value": {
         "Dusty Peak": 2,
         "Mushroom Alley": 4,
         "Windy Falls": 1
     }
 }
```

Thought it **is** all done on the server, it's not without it's costs, and not only in the JavaScript interpretaion. The mapReduce process works by often calling the `reducer` function multiple times, meaning that output from the reducer can actually end up as it's input ( a key design point ). From this perspective it means that on successive passes the result object will "grow", and this means more overhead when iterating and testing for the presence of keys.

The alternate aggregation framework process handles this in a much more natural way, and with efficient algorithms in the `$group` data collection.

Comment: Now that I think about it, `trails` being a list of objects works better. Thank you!

Comment: @fosskers Thanks for the vote of confidence, but it would also be appreciated if you [accepted the answer.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with aggregate using a compound index (effectively grouping by hiker and trail, then doing a second $group on the hiker_id, and this time pushing the trail name and count.  For example:

```
db.hikes.aggregate([
    {$group:{_id:{"hiker_id":"$hiker_id", "trail":"$trail"},count:{$sum:1}}}, 
    {$group:{_id:"$_id.hiker_id", trails:{$push:{"trail":"$_id.trail","count":"$count"}}}}
])
```

So the first part group with a compount _id which is a combination of hiker_id and trail, then the second part regroups just on hiker_id, and pushes the trail name and count.

So given a collection like this:

```
> db.hikes.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d8b6bb3e30c2d1435acf96"), "hiker_id" : 123, "trail" : "Dusty Peak" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d8b6d83e30c2d1435acf97"), "hiker_id" : 123, "trail" : "Foo" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d8b6da3e30c2d1435acf98"), "hiker_id" : 123, "trail" : "Dusty Peak" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d8b6de3e30c2d1435acf99"), "hiker_id" : 123, "trail" : "Foo" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d8b6e63e30c2d1435acf9a"), "hiker_id" : 123, "trail" : "Bar" }
```

You would get a result like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 123,
    "trails" : [
        {
            "trail" : "Bar",
            "count" : 1
        },
        {
            "trail" : "Foo",
            "count" : 2
        },
        {
            "trail" : "Dusty Peak",
            "count" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```